# How do I rearrange order of comments?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, for-loop, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a comment system, and it's a little messed up. It's listing comments from old to new, when I need it to go in the reverse order (newest on top). How do I do this?

Code: (/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb)

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
        <p>
                <strong>
                        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
                </strong>
                <br/>
                <%= comment.body %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

Edit:
Here is the comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @post }
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a single comment partial or views altogether. A sequence of comments should be fetched by a controller.

Comment: I still fail to see where is a sequence of comments fetched. A single comment template and comment creation action, none are relevant.

Comment: @D-side In my `models/post.rb` I have a `has_many :comments`. I think I could add `, :order => ''` to the end of that, but I don't know what to order it by. I tried `created_at` and `created_at DESC`

Comment: No, that's not what I mean, but I see what's needed. You are fetching post's associated comments in view, apparently, like `@post.comments`, right? It's a little odd to tag with `for-loop` without actual code with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Comment model, add:

```
default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

This way, `@post.comments` will be properly ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Using default scopes can easily be confusing, because if I tried `Comment.order(:id)` I would actually get `select * from comments order by created_at desc, id asc` which might take time in debugging wondering why aren't they ordered by id, and to avoid that you need to do something like `Comment.unscoped.order(:id)` which is annoying if you ask me, instead i would prefer doing a scope that i could invoke only when i know i need it

```
scope :chronological_order -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

Then call it

```
Comment.chronological_order
```

of course you can pick whatever scope name you prefer.

Comment: `reorder` looks way better than `unscope.order`, even though the meaning is the same. And `default_scope` tends to make code shorter and DRYer in cases when you apply a certain scope more often, than not. Just the other side of this.